# Is there a best practice to have customized image preprocessing in Apache Tika OCR from PDF?

Tags: pdf, ocr, apache-tika

When feeding pdf files with scanned/photographed images inside to Apache Tika, the processor extracts the images (if configured properly) and hands them to tesseract. This works very well for images that are in a proper shape for OCR (originating from a paper scanner), but not when originating from a phone camera, e.g.
Is there a way to have an own image preprocessor invoked by Tika for each image page just before it is sent to tesseract?

Comment: Register your own `Parser` with Apache Tika for the appropriate image types, have that check and delegate to Tesseract if appropriate?

Comment: @Gagravarr that's a reasonable solution. Since Tika already has a nice parser to do all this (extract images, configure tesseract, call it), I was hoping there is a way to hook in just my own image processing, e.g. using a template method pattern or something like this.

Comment: I think the best way is probably to wrap the Tika parser you want with your own code, register your parser instead, and delegate to the real Tika Parser as appropriate

Comment: Thanx, will try it that way.

Comment: I found (in the code :)) that TesseractOCRParser.java already has image pre-processing for OCR using ImageMagick in processImage.

We tried ImageMagick but had better results using OpenCV (before using Tika) - but we will reevalute our findings and check if ImageMagick will do the job es well. Do you think, though, that including OpenCV at that point as an alternative would be feasible? (I have seen that there is also a connection in another context with TIKA-2322 already.)

Comment: At this point, you're probably best off asking on the Apache Tika users mailing list!